# Magento2: Failed Override Magento_Tax module Class with protected method

Tags: magento2, override-model

I am trying to override class *Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector*

I tried everything and checked the implementation is correct in di.xml

The method I am trying to override is a protected method **processProductItems()**

I have no clue what am I doing wrong here. It keeps calling the function from the original Magento_Tax class

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector"
        type="Folio3\TaxCollector\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector"/>
</config>
```

Override class *Folio3\TaxCollector\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector.php*

```
class CommonTaxCollector extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector
{
...
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Folio3_TaxCollector" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
            <module name="Magento_User"/>
            <module name="Magento_Tax" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong here? I think I have followed all the necessary steps. It keeps calling the original **CommonTaxCollector.php** class from **Magento_Tax** module

Comment: Is there any error that you are facing?

Comment: Facing No errors at all

Comment: Can you check changing scope of your di.xml? Where it is sitting currently? Global?

Comment: Tried with global and frontend both scopes, no luck

Comment: can you share your overrided function `processProductItems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are overriding the wrong class.

```
Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector
```

The class **CommonTaxCollector** is not used directly, Magento2 used a **Tax** class which overrides the **CommonTaxCollector** class.

```
vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php
```

Tax.php

```
namespace Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;
....

class Tax extends CommonTaxCollector {
```

## Solution:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax"
        type="Folio3\TaxCollector\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax"/>
</config>
```

Override class Folio3\TaxCollector\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax.php

```
class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax
{
...
```

It should work fine!

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot